# Proving linear dependency for two vector groups

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification

## The question:

Let V be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $S = \{v,u,w\}$ be a group of 3 vectors in V.
Let T be defined as $T = \{v, 
v + u,
v + u + 2w
\}$.
Prove that if S is linearly dependent, then also T is linearly dependent.

---

### The proof:

Let's assume that S is linearly dependent, and assume to the contrary that T is linearly independent.

Thus, for $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3 \in \mathbb{R}$, if the following exists:
$$\lambda_1v + \lambda_2(v + u) + \lambda_3 (v + u + 2w) = 0$$
Then, *necessarily* $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 0$.
Rearranging the equation:
$$(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3)v + (\lambda_2 + \lambda_3)u + 2\lambda_3w = 0$$

But it is given that S is linearly dependent, therefore the above equation is suppose to be true also for $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ which aren't all zero.
This is in contradiction that T is linearly dependent, therefore T must be linearly independent.
Q.E.D.

---

Is the proof correct?
If not, why?
Could you forumlate a proof in a similar method which is correct?

Comment: Here is a counterexample in ${\mathbb R}^2$. $v=(1,0)$, $u=(0,2)$, $w=(0,-1)$. Then $S=\{v,u,w\}$ is linearly dependent because $u+2w=0$. But $T= \{ (1,0), (1,2) \}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: You mean a "set" of three vectors, not a "group".

Comment: @DerekHolt: But T should contain **3** vectors, thus, using your example: $T = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$, which is linearly dependent.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom As my counterexample shows, the result as stated is false for sets of three vectors, because it is possible for $T$ to have fewer than $3$ vectors. Linear independence, spanning,basis, etc, should be defined as properties of sequences (or ordered sets) of vectors, not plain sets.

Comment: @Dor But the set $T$ that you have written down quite clearly contains only $2$ vectors, and it is linearly independent.

Comment: @DerekHolt a fair point. Still not a group, though.

Comment: @DerekHolt: So either the question assumes a false claim or the example that you gave doesn't apply... Right here you showed why it's not true that `if S is linearly dependent, then also T is linearly dependent.`. Or, maybe the example that you gave isn't enough, because that T must have 3 vectors (as defined in the question), yet in your example it has 2 vectors. Can you bring a counter-example in which T has 3 vectors?

Comment: No, if $S$ and $T$ both have three vectors, then the statement is correct. The question did say that $S$ has three vectors, but not $T$. You could call my objection a quibble, but I think people who set exercises for students should take care to get them tight.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh, so **bottom line - the question isn't defined properly.** Is that correct? Also, referring to the example above (specifically to the set T) - why when a set has 3 vectors, 2 of them are the same vector - then it is said the the set actually has 2 vectors? Can't we say that two of its vectors are the same - thus inferring that the set is linearly dependent?

Comment: @DerekHolt: Actually the definition of a set in Wikipedia explains it all: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29 . Though I'd be glad to see your reply! :)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Could you please briefly explain regarding that T and S aren't a group? Thanks!

Comment: @Dor see the definition of a group [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29).  Your set is not one of these.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: So T and S aren't a group because they don't have [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28mathematics%29). Is that correct..?

Comment: Right.  You could say, for example, that any vector space is a group under the operation of addition. However, it is rare to consider groups in the context of introductory linear algebra.

Comment: It is usually a tacit assumption in the context of linear algebra that the collections of vectors in question are secretly sequences; i.e. order matters and duplicates may occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a valid way of doing the problem:

We want to show that if $T$ is linearly independent, then so is $S$ (thus proving the desired statement by contrapositive).  Suppose $T$ is linearly independent.  Let $c_i$ be such that
$$
c_1 v + c_2 u + c_3 w = 0
$$
We would like to show that all $c_i$ are zero, thus proving that $S$ is linearly independent.  We note that
$$
c_1 v + c_2 u + c_3 w = \\
(c_1 - c_2)v
+(c_2 - c_3/2)(v+u)
+(c_3/2)(v + u + 2w) = 0
$$
Because $T$ is linearly independent, we may conclude that
$$
c_1 - c_2 = 0\\
c_2 - c_3/2 = 0\\
c_3/2 = 0
$$
From the above, we may conclude that $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0$.  Thus, $S$ is linearly independent, as desired.

Comment: Minor fix - instead of $(c_1 - c_2)u$ it should be $(c_1 - c_2)v$. I still don't see why my proof isn't similar to the one that you've written... my proof absolutely express the same idea.. only difference is that the coefficients vector ($c_i$) is firstly represented by the set S, and then is transformed to be represented by the set T. (I did the opposite)

Comment: What you would need to show in order to complete your proof is that for every set of coefficients $c_i$ (as I used them), we can find $\lambda_i$ such that
$$
c_1 = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3\\
c_2 = \lambda_2 + \lambda_3\\
c_3 = 2\lambda_3
$$
In retrospect, this is what I should have said from the beginning.

At any rate, the crux of why the statement is true is that the system
$$
\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = c_1\\
\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = c_2\\
2\lambda_3 = c_3
$$
**always** has a (unique) solution for $\lambda_i$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have a contradiction, until you give a way for providing a set of coefficients $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ that are not all zero.

There's a simpler way: the span of $T=\{v,v+u,v+u+2w\}$ is clearly contained in the span of $S=\{u,v,w\}$, because
$$
\lambda_1v + \lambda_2(v + u) + \lambda_3 (v + u + 2w) =
(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3)v + (\lambda_2 + \lambda_3)u + 2\lambda_3w
$$
as you computed.

Since the dimension of the span of $S$ is at most $2$, because $S$ is linearly dependent, the span of $T$ has dimension at most $2$. Therefore $T$ is linearly dependent.

---

The objection that $u,v,w$ are meant to be distinct is invalid. For instance, if $w=v$, we'd have $T=\{v,v+u,u+3v\}$, but again this would be linearly dependent. The only way it couldn't be is that the three expressions denote the same non zero vector, because the span of $S$ has dimension at most $1$. Let's see: $v=v+u$ entails $u=0$ and $v=u+3v$ entails $v=0$. So certainly $T$ is linearly dependent.

Similarly, if $w=u$ we have $T=\{v,v+u,v+3u\}$ and the same reasoning holds.

If $u=v$, we have $T=\{u,2u,2u+2w\}$ and so $u=2u$ means $u=0$.

But there's really no need to do this analysis.

Comment: Thanks, that's another point of view. May I assume that the equations that I've written tell the same story (of the span)? I mean, using my method - I had to show that for every $\lambda_i$, there's a corresponding $c_i$ (as was written by Omnomnomnom). But by using the words "span" etc. we're allowed to omit that connection between the coefficients ($\lambda_i$ and $c_i$). Is that correct..?

Comment: @Dor Yes, that's essentially the same, but the other way around. Of course we're using the fundamental facts about dimension.